# List<string> binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have been reading hundreds of posts on ASP.NET blogs and questions on StackOverflow but I can't find a solution to this (apparently) simple problem. Here is a simplified version:

Question Class

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionBody { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I have a simple form for the creation of a Question object. I know there isn't an automatic EditorFor for collections, so I have tried with:

In my form:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextBox("Answers")
     @Html.TextBox("Answers")
     @Html.TextBox("Answers")
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Question question, List<string> Answers)
 ...
```

The answers are correctly passed but they are not being binded to my model!

**Question #1**: Does exist a way to automatically tie this List of strings to the List of strings contained in my Question model?

Then I tried to "force" this List to be the List in my model, doing:

```
   question.Answers = Answers;
   db.Questions.Add(question);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

But my collection is always being passed as empty. I think this is due to the ASP.NET MVC model binding and validation.

So, **Question #2**: Does exist a way to "modify" my *question* object just before it is saved to the database with db.SaveChanges() ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to create an editor template for your list see here:

[Editor Templates for List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301790/editor-templates-for-liststring)

or you can simply put

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextArea("Answers")
</div>
```

then the returning info will arrive as string and you can then split that string by line and make a list of it using Linq extensions:

```
public ActionResult Create(Question question, string answers)
{
    var answerList = answers.Split('\n').ToList();
     question.Answers = answerList;
     db.Questions.Add(question);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use the second solution, but only because I can't understand the first one. A collection (List) of strings should be a basic type, it's not a complex object with properties. Do I really need to create an EditorTemplate to render a simple textbox and pass the list to the controller? (Note that I'm already able to pass it to the controller, as I have previously said, but the List is not being binded to the model!).